# Paginação com url amigavel

Tags: php, url-amigável

To usando url amigavel e paginação, porem se eu estou na pagina `1` e clico para ir para a pagina `2` nada acontence, mas na minha url fica o caminho correto `localhost/produtos/emagrecimento/pagina/2/` porém e exibido os mesmo produtos da pagina 1.

```
//recuperar o id passado pela url
$url = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url'] : '';
$explode = explode('/', $url);
$categoria = mysqli_real_escape_string($conecta, $explode[1]);

//Verificar se esta sendo passado na URL a pagina atual, senao  atribuida a pagina 
$pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;
if ($pagina <= 0) {
header('Location: produtos.php');
} else {

//Selecionar todos os produtos da tabela
$sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos";
$query = mysqli_query($conecta, $sql);

//Contar o total de produtos
$total_linhas = mysqli_num_rows($query);


//Seta a quantidade de produtos por pagina
$quantidade_pg = 3;

//calcular o numero de pagina necessarias para apresentar os produtos
$num_pagina = ceil($total_linhas / $quantidade_pg);



//Calcular o inicio da visualizacao
$incio = ($quantidade_pg * $pagina) - $quantidade_pg;

//Selecionar os produtos a serem apresentado na pagina
$sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE categoria='$categoria' ORDER BY nome ASC limit $incio, $quantidade_pg";
$query = mysqli_query($conecta, $sql);
$query_produtos = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$linha_produtos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
}
```

exibe os dados

```
 <?php
    while ($linha_produtos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                        ?>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">

               <div class="cause">
                    <img src="<?php echo pg ?>/assets/images/produtos/<?php echo $linha_produtos['imagem_produto'] ?>" alt="" class="cause-img img-thumbnail img">
                    <h4 class="cause-title"><a href="#"><?php echo $linha_produtos['nome'] ?></a></h4>
                        <div class="cause-details">
                    <?php echo limitarTexto($linha_produtos['descricao'], $limite = 200); ?>
                        </div>
                    <h2 class="title-style-3"><?php echo $linha_produtos['valor']; ?></h2>
                    <div class="btn-holder text-center">
                         <a href="" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" 
                                       data-target="#saberModal" 
                                       data-nome="<?php echo $linha_produtos['nome']; ?>"
                                       data-descricao="<?php echo $linha_produtos['descricao'] ?>"
                                       data-valor="<?php echo $linha_produtos['valor'] ?>"
                                       >
                                        SABER MAIS</a>
                                </div>
                            </div> 

                        </div> 
                    <?php } ?>
```

paginação

```
<?php
                                    if ($num_pagina > 1 && $pagina <= $num_pagina) {
                                        for ($i = $inicio; $i <= $fim; $i++) {
                                            ?>
                                            <?php
                                            if ($pagina == $i) {
                                                ?>
                                                <li  class="active"><a href="<?php echo pg . '/' . 'produtos/' . $categoria . '/pagina/' . $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>


                                            <?php } else { ?>

                                                <li><a href="<?php echo pg . '/' . 'produtos/' . $categoria . '/pagina/' . $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
                                                <?php
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Causa**

O que eu notei no seu código, é que você está buscando o parâmetro 'pagina' na url por GET, só que 'pagina' faz parte de um parâmetro que você setou no rewrite engine.

Se no rewrite você colocou 'url', então essa URL que você passou, seria o mesmo que `http://localhost/?url=produtos/emagrecimento/pagina/2/`

Sendo assim, só existe o parâmetro `$_GET['url']` no `$_GET`, e a página está contina nele, então não existe o $_GET['pagina']. O valor do `$_GET['url']` é = produtos/emagrecimento/pagina/2/

Então, está retornando os resultados da página 1, porque na sua condição ternária da `$página`, você fez `$pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;`

Por isso, se não existe a `$_GET['pagina']`, a `$pagina` vai ser sempre = 1, por isso vem só os resultados de pagina 1 sempre.

**Solução**

O número da página atual está na variável `$explode` que você criou, ele é o quarto índice do array `$explode`.

Então, a variável `$pagina` tem que ser assim: `$pagina = (isset($explode[3]))  ? $explode[3] : 1;`

Faça essa alteração e teste aí.

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu precisava, muito obrigada pela ajuda :D.

Comment: Por nada. Que bom que ajudei. =)